# USB Connector Current Rating for Charging

Tags: usb, connector, charging

I have heard it mentioned that the current rating for a USB charger is dependent on the current rating of the USB port itself; ie a Type A connector has to be rated for 2A on a charger that says it supports 2A.

How true is this statement?

Looking on DigiKey, I am having trouble finding USB Type A connectors with a current rating of over 1.5A.  There are some that list 1 to 1.5A; many have no current rating at all!

Where are these high current USB ports for charging and how can I find them?

Comment: What do the datasheets say? Digi key doesn't always list it

Comment: Datasheets are listing 1 to 1.5A, and some no rating at all.  DigiKey itself does not list current ratings on USB connectors.

Comment: Well, it's not like it'll explode if someone pulls 2A through a 1A plug, it'll just heat up more than it would have otherwise, which can be 20+ 'C sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement is strangely formulated. It would be more logical to say that the current rating of the USB connector of a USB charger product must comply with the rating of the whole charger.

In short: you can't build a USB charger that says it can deliver 2A if the connector is rated for only 1.5A. That is true.

In the end, if you're looking for type A connectors rated for higher current than the typical 1.5A, here is one: Wurth 614004190021. Rated 3A. Found on Mouser: they have a rated current filter for USB connectors.